# How to solve the next limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Good day.

Let's call the limit $L$

I get a solution on my own to it but when I attempted to verify it was right, by using Symbolab and other software, they did not work.

Assuming $a\in R$, $$L:= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\frac{a^4(a+h)-a(a+h)^4}{(a+h)^3+(-a)^3}$$

I get zero as result,yet I am not sure if it's right the way I solved for **L**.

Thank you.

Comment: If $a\neq 0$ the numerator becomes $a^5 \neq 0$ and the denominator becomes $0$ so it should be divergent

Comment: @JesusisSaviour How exactly did you get your result "zero" for $L$?

Answer (score 1):

Using the L-Hopitals Rule on $L$, we get,
$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^4 - (a^4 + 12a^2h + 12a^2h^2 + 4h^3)}{3a^2 + 6ah +3h^2}$$
*(taking derivatives of Numerator and denominator)*

So, this can easily be evaluated to **$0$**, just by substituting $h=0$. Thus, $L = 0$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But due to the different result @William-Elliot gave I am not sure then what is right

Comment: You forgot the leading $\frac{1}{h}$.

Comment: Also, in the brackets, it should be $4a^4$ instead of $a^4$.

Comment: @eudes to take derivates u would have to use binomial theorem, so cancelling out the terms u would get the result as above, i hope...

Comment: What I mean is:
$$
a(a+h)^4 = a(a^4+4a^3h+6a^2h^2+\ldots)
\\ \frac d{dh} a(a^4+4a^3h+6a^2h^2+\ldots) = 0+4a^4+12a^2h+\ldots
$$
or:
$$
\frac d{dh} a(a+h)^4 = 4a(a+h)^3 = 4a^4 + 12a^2h+\ldots
$$

Answer (score 0):

If a is positive, the numerator goes positive and the denominator goes to zero.
When a = 0, the expression goes to 1/0.
If a is negative, then the numerator goes negative and the demoninator goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Expand all the brackets:
\begin{multline}
\frac{1}{h}\frac{a^4(a+h)-a(a+h)^4}{(a+h)^3+(-a)^3}
= \frac{1}{h}\frac{a^5 + a^4h -a(a^4+4a^3h+6a^2h^2+4ah^3+h^4)}{a^3+3a^2h+3ah^2+h^3-a^3}
\\= \frac{1}{h}\frac{a^5 + a^4h - a^5-4a^4h-6a^3h^2-4a^2h^3-ah^4}{3a^2h+3ah^2+h^3}
= \frac{1}{h}\frac{-3a^4h-6a^3h^2-4a^2h^3-ah^4}{3a^2h+3ah^2+h^3} \stackrel{\cdot \frac {1/h} {1/h}}=
\\= \frac {1}{h} \frac{-3a^4-6a^3h-4a^2h^2-ah^3}{3a^2+3ah+h^2}
= \frac{-3a^4-6a^3h-4a^2h^2-ah^3}{3a^2h+3ah^2+h^3}
\end{multline}

If $a=0$, then the last expression is $0/h^3 = 0$, so $L=0$.
If not, for $h\to 0$ the numerator is negative (it tends to $-3a^4$), but the denominator tends to $0$, so the limit doesn't exist.

However, note that if there weren't $\frac 1 h$ in the original expression, then the limit would be $-a^2$:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{-3a^4-6a^3h-4a^2h^2-ah^3}{3a^2+3ah+h^2} = 
\frac{-3a^4}{3a^2} = -a^2
$$

Edit: I'm leaving this answer, because this way *always does the job*, although it might sometimes need some work. See also my second answer, which works only for specific examples, but it's worth trying first for any example, as it doesn't take much time.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, if you note *something*:
$$
\frac{1}{h}\frac{a^4(a+h)-a(a+h)^4}{(a+h)^3+(-a)^3}
= \frac{1}{h}\frac{a(a+h)\big(a^3 - (a+h)^3\big)}{(a+h)^3-a^3}
= -\frac{1}{h} a(a+h) = \frac {-a(a+h)}{h}
$$

If $a=0$, then the last expression is constantly $0$, so $L=0$.
If not, for $h\to 0$ the numerator is negative (it tends to $-a^2$), but the denominator tends to $0$, so the limit doesn't exist.

Again, if there weren't $\frac 1 h$ in the original expression, then the limit would be $-a^2$.

I'm leaving my first answer, because that way *always does the job*, although it might sometimes need some work. The solution here works only for specific examples (but it's worth trying first for any example, as it doesn't take much time).